# Regex: Start start search with one character and end with another

Tags: regex

I am trying to strip out the filename in a full path by doing the following:

1. Search for the last '\' in the path
2. Select the filename until the '|' is encountered

Example:
c:\folder1\subfolder1\subfolder2\example.xls | rev. 12345 on 2020-01-01

Here is the regex i have so far that gets me to "**example.xls | rev. 12345 on 2020-01-01**"

`\\([^\\]*)$`

I only want "example.xls" and not the rest.

I am a complete RegEx newbie and can't seem to figure out how to search from the last "\" in the path until the "\".

Comment: You know that `$` means "end of the line", right?  And your regex doesn't seem to say anything about `|`.

Comment: I was unsure how to add in the '|' which is why i posted the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search until `|`, but `$` matches the end of the line.

Make your character set exclude backslash and `|`.

```
\\([^\\|]*)\s*\|
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/7gkKTE/1)

Comment: That worked and thank you for the quick turnaround!  I appreciate it.